# Is there a way to identify whether photo is taken from camera or attachment in MicrosoftBot Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, botframework, whatsapp

I am developing a chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I am trying to add Azure FaceRecognization in in Bot & its working fine. and when I take a photo from whatsapp I am getting that image as a URL in attachment **context.activity.attachments[0].contentUrl** and if I upload a photo also i am getting image in same attachment as a URL, is there a way where I can identify whether photo is taken from Camera or attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be up to the client/channel (Whatsapp) to send across in channel data. I do not know if Whatsapp does this already, but you can check the `ChannelData` property of the **activity** received by the bot.

If not there, then no luck for the moment. You would need to check with Whatsapp and see if this is something that configured or implemented.